# Arabic Song from "Zaki Chan"

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

https://youtu.be/_7tSx9b6HiY

It's an arabic song known from the movie Zaki Chan. Anyone help???

Answer (score 1):

Artist: Medhat Saleh

Song Name: متحلمشي (Mthelmha)

http://6rbtop.co/audio/6be227ea1cbc